# How to create tree view with checkboxes in extjs4

Tags: checkbox, extjs4, treeview

I am working in Extjs4. I want to create tree view with checkBoxes for selection of individual entry.
I have json as-

```
{"data":[{"Maincategory":"Main","maincategoryId":"1","Subcategory":{"subcategory":"GK","categoryId":"2"},{"subcategory":"History","categoryId":"3"},{"subcategory":"Geography","categoryId":"4"}]},{"Maincategory":"GK","maincategoryId":"2","Subcategory":[{"subcategory":"environment","categoryId":"5"}]},{"Maincategory":"History","maincategoryId":"3","Subcategory":[{"subcategory":"civics","categoryId":"7"}]},{"Maincategory":"Geography","maincategoryId":"4","Subcategory":[{"subcategory":"India","categoryId":"8"}]},{"Maincategory":"environment","maincategoryId":"5","Subcategory":[]}]}
```

i want to create tree view of this json. So how to create tree view with checkboxes in extjs4.

Answer (score 0):

Add Ext.selection.CheckboxModel as selectionmodel to your treepanel

Some thing like this

```
{
 xtype: 'treepanel',
 style: 'margin-top: 10px;',
 itemId: 'searchresultstreepanel',
 flex: 1,
 autoScroll : true,
 store: me.searchResultsStore,
 rootVisible: false,
 loadMask: true,
 selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel',{
     mode: 'MULTI'
 }),
 selType: 'treemodel',
 .....
```